# Proving that a family of exponential operators has a uniform bound, without semigroup theory.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras, functional-calculus

Set $T\in B(X)$ for some arbitrary Banach space $X$. Define the family of operators $\{e^{tT}\}_{t\in\mathbb R}$ via the holomorphic functional calculus. I have been able to prove, using basic facts about the functional calculus that $\frac{d}{dt}e^{tT}=Te^{tT}$, and that the family forms a group under multiplication.

What I am now trying to prove is that if $\sigma(T)\subset\{z:Rez<0\}$, then $\sup_{t\geq 0} \|e^{tT}\|\leq M$ for some positive $M$. In the finite dimensional case, I know we can decompose into Jordan's normal form to get the result, but I do not know how to pursue that avenue for an arbitrary bounded operator. My idea is to somehow use the spectral mapping theorem. This gives us that the spectral radius $\rho (e^{tT})\to 0$ as $t\to \infty$, and that this convergence is exponential. Unfortunately, as $X$ need not be a Hilbert space and $T$ need not be normal we do not know that $\rho(e^{tT})=\|e^{tT}\|$. What I am hoping is that there is some way we can extend the [estimation lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma) to the holomorphic functional calculus, at least in certain cases of which this is one, which would then give the result, but I have not been able to find such a thing.

From scouring the net I know that this is an archetypal problem of continuous semi-group theory, but I encountered this while studying Rudin's *Functional Analysis*, specifically in relation to his chapter on Banach algebras and the holomorphic functional calculus, which makes me believe that there is a simpler solution using basic theory from these areas. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does $\rho(x)=||x||$ have to do with commutativity?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich ahh absolutely nothing as far as I am aware. I misread something on another site last night when I was half asleep. I'll remove that part now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $\gamma$ is a closed curve in the left complex half-plane that "encloses" $\sigma(T)$. Then, if I'm remembering this stuff correctly, $$e^{tT}=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma e^{tz}(zI-T)^{-1}\,dz.$$

But we have $$\left|e^{tz}\right|\le1\quad(t>0,z\in\gamma)$$and$$\sup_{z\in\gamma}||(zI-T)^{-1}||<\infty.$$

If that's right I bet it's the argument Rudin had in mind; he's a big fan of using CIF for the functional calculus.

**Edit:** I felt a little guilty posting this, taking advantage of the fact that the OP said $\sigma(T)\subset\{x+iy:x<0\}$; the argument doesn't  quite work if $\sigma(T)$ is just contained in the closed left half-plane. But **aha**, in that case the result is  not true! Let $$T=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix};$$since $T^2=0$ we have $$e^{tT}=\begin{bmatrix}1&t\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

**Edit 2:** I also felt that the "right" argument should show that $||e^{tT}||\le1$. But that's not true either: Let $A_\delta=2T-\delta I$, where $T$ is as in the previous edit. Then $\lim_{\delta\to0^+}||e^{A_\delta}||=||e^{2T}||>1$.

Looks like CIT gives the whole truth.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is similar to what I had in mind, but I have been unable to prove rigorously that $\|\int_\gamma f(z)(zI-T)^{-1}dz\|\leq \sup|_{z\in \gamma}|f(z)|\sup_{z\in\gamma}\|zI-T)^{-1}\|$. Now though I've found Thm 3.29 in Rudin, which I believe gives the result: If $Q$ is a compact Hausdorff space, $f:Q\to X$ with $X$, Banach, and $\mu$ a positive Borel measure on $Q$ then $\|\int_Q f d\mu\|\leq \int_Q \|f\|d\mu$. I believe this is what I am looking for?

Comment: @K.Power Yes. In fact the fact that $||\int f||\le\int||f||$ is trivial from the definition of the integral  via duality  (and the Hahn-Banach theorem).

Comment: Yes, I feel a bit silly now that I didn't think of it earlier. Thanks again, this is exactly what I was looking for.